# Returning unique strings from two arrays of strings, concatenated in one string VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, boolean, string-concatenation

I have a code that is close to working but not quite. I have two arrays astrArray1 and astrArray2 and the function findUniques() is supposed to return the unique strings(names) among the two arrays. I can get the code to return the names that they have in common but it doesn't return the correct value for the ones that are unique. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
Function findUniques(astrArray1() As String, astrArray2() As String) As String


Dim blnMP5 As Boolean
blnMP5 = True

Dim counter1 As Long
Dim counter2 As Long

Dim uniquesString As String
uniquesString = " "

For counter1 = LBound(astrArray1) To UBound(astrArray1)
  For counter2 = LBound(astrArray2) To UBound(astrArray2)
    If astrArray1(counter1) <> astrArray2(counter2) Then
      blnMP5 = False
    ElseIf astrArray1(counter1) = astrArray2(counter2) Then
      blnMP5 = True
    End If
    If blnMP5 = False Then
      uniquesString = uniquesString & "," & astrArray2(counter2)
    End If
  Next counter2
Next counter1

findUniques = uniquesString
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyAr1(1 To 4) As String
    Dim MyAr2(1 To 2) As String

    MyAr1(1) = "aaa": MyAr1(2) = "bbb": MyAr1(3) = "ccc": MyAr1(4) = "ddd"
    MyAr2(1) = "aaa": MyAr2(2) = "bbb"

    '~~> This will give you ccc,ddd
    Debug.Print findUniques(MyAr1, MyAr2)
End Sub

Function findUniques(astrArray1() As String, astrArray2() As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim uniquesString As String
    Dim matchFound As Boolean

    For i = LBound(astrArray1) To UBound(astrArray1)
        matchFound = False
        For j = LBound(astrArray2) To UBound(astrArray2)
            If astrArray1(i) = astrArray2(j) Then
                matchFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If matchFound = False Then uniquesString = uniquesString & "," & astrArray1(i)
    Next i

    findUniques = Mid(uniquesString, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would this work even if one array is longer than the other?

Comment: See the answer above. One array IS bigger than the other :)